# Cakephp: make multiple checkbox behave like radio button

Tags: jquery, css, cakephp

Is it possible to make my multiple checkbox only one can be checked?

Here is my code:

```
$notiWhen = array(
  'daily' => 'Daily',
  'weekly' => 'Weekly',
  'never' => 'Never',
);
echo $this->Form->input('notify_when', array('label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $notiWhen, 'selected' => 'daily'));
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery try something like that

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function (evt) {
        $("input:checkbox").not($(this)).removeAttr("checked");
        $(this).attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
    });
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CPdL/)